# Unable to draw loading screen in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, textures, loading, asset-management

I'm currently trying to implement a loading screen for a game.

```java
private enum STATE {
    LOADING, START_MENU, PLAYING, PAUSE, GAME_OVER
}

private STATE state = STATE.LOADING;
```

These are the game states, so it starts with `LOADING`, so it can run the `LOADING` case in the render method.

```java
public void show() {
    startMenuBackground = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("startMenuBackground.png"));
    startMenuBackgroundSplit = new TextureRegion(startMenuBackground).split(32, 32);
    assetManager = new AssetManager();

    for (int appleImage = 0; appleImage < apple.length; appleImage++)
        assetManager.load("bits/" + appleImage + ".png", Texture.class);

    for (int bodyImage = 0; bodyImage < snakeBody.length; bodyImage++)
        assetManager.load("body/" + bodyImage + ".png", Texture.class);

    for(int backgroundImage = 0; backgroundImage < background.length; backgroundImage++)
        assetManager.load("background/" + backgroundImage + ".png", Texture.class);

    assetManager.load("KappaMan.png", Texture.class);
    assetManager.load("playButton/0.png", Texture.class);
    assetManager.load("playButton/1.png", Texture.class);
    assetManager.load("title.png", Texture.class);
    assetManager.load("AmenoSandstorm.mp3", Music.class);
    assetManager.load("beMad.mp3", Music.class);
    assetManager.load("collide.mp3", Music.class);
    assetManager.finishLoading();
```

This is the beginning of the `show` method which loads all assets for the game.

```java
startMenuBackgroundSplit = new TextureRegion(startMenuBackground).split(32, 32);
```

This is how progress of the game loading is displayed. (I think this is the part that's causing the issue, and the reason the game just renders a black screen.)

```java
case LOADING:
    if (assetManager.update()) {
        state = STATE.START_MENU;
    } else {
        progress = assetManager.getProgress();
        tilesToLoad = 576 * progress;
        tilesY = (int)tilesToLoad / 32;
        tilesX = (int)tilesToLoad % 32;
    }

    break;
```

Now I begin loading all assets for the game while it runs `LOADING`. So if it's true, it will go to the `START_MENU`, if not then it checks the progress. `tilesY` is the number of rows that I would need to load of the `startMenuBackground`, `tilesX` is the number of tiles I'd need to load on the bottom row of what progress there has been of the `startMenuBackgroundSplit`.

```java
if (state == STATE.LOADING) {
    for (int tilesYLoad = 0; tilesYLoad < tilesY; tilesYLoad++) {
        if(tilesYLoad != tilesY - 1) {
            for(int tilesXLoad = 0; tilesXLoad < 32; tilesXLoad++)
                batch.draw(startMenuBackgroundSplit[tilesXLoad][tilesYLoad], tilesXLoad * 32, tilesYLoad * 32);

        } else {
            for(int tilesXLoad = 0; tilesXLoad < tilesX; tilesXLoad++)
                batch.draw(startMenuBackgroundSplit[tilesXLoad][tilesYLoad], tilesXLoad * 32, tilesYLoad * 32);
        }
    }
}
```

I have this code which will draw all the relevant tiles depending on the progress of loading all assets.

```java
if (state == STATE.LOADING) {
    layout.setText(loadingFont, LOADING_TEXT);
    loadingFont.draw(batch, LOADING_TEXT, 0, layout.height);
}
```

There is also this to write loading at the bottom left.

I've commented out the `START_MENU` state, so I could see the state of the background when it would normally forward the user to the `START_MENU` screen. It displays the text. `Loading...`, but it doesn't display the background at all.

I can not tell what I have done wrong. Could I have guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assetManager.finishLoading() blocks until everything is loaded. Which means your show() method will not finish until all your assets are loaded.

Instead of calling finishLoading(), you should call assetManager.update() inside your render method. This allows your assets to be loaded, but also doesn't block, so your render method can do what you want.

update() will return false if there are more assets to load, and true when everything is done loading. So you'll need to check the result from each call to update() and proceed accordingly.